# Is there any performance difference between IN and = operators in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query where in the age is to checked against an array of possible-possible-values.

The query looks like :

```
select * from users where age in (15,18,20,22);
```

Some times, the ages-array might only have a single value, say [22].

In such circumstances, am wondering if the following query (A):

```
select * from users where age in (22);
```

will be optimum when compared to (B):

```
select * from users where age = 22;
```

Please, let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Compare the query plans.

Comment: Query plans appear to be the same when I try it on my DB here. MySQL is likely smart enough to figure out they're the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As much i know `IN` clause is internally implemented as a series of where clauses like

```
WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3
```

Please correct me if I am wrong...

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is any performance difference between `IN` and `=` operators in MySQL.

We use `=` operator when trying to compare a single element and when we have to compare list of elements we use `IN` clause.

Anyways, `IN` clause internally gets flatten as series of `OR` condition/OR'ed stack ... like

```
col1 IN('a','b','c')
```

Will become

```
col = 'a' OR col1 = 'b' OR col = 'c'
```

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a performance impact on using

```
... Id in (22)
```

Vs

```
... Id=22
```

The execution plan for both statements will be identical, the IN statement will be transformed to '=22' when the list in the IN only has one element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` clause to replace many `OR` conditions. So

```
SELECT * FROM colA = 'Value1' or colA = 'Value2'
```

is the same as

```
SELECT * FROM colA IN ('Value1', 'Value2')
```